# Mongo DB aggregate $lookup slow add index to all documents?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I've got two collections in my Mongo DB database. I'm quite new to Mongo DB in general.  Each of my collection says that there's 1 index, now, coming from a Laravel and SQL database where I can improve performance by adding an index with `->index()` on my migration for my columns, I assume there's a way to do something similar for my Mongo DB documents and the key/value fields.

I've got two collections:

- data_source_one (# of documents: 5,300, total doc size: 1.2 MB)
- data_source_two (# of documents: 6,800, total doc size: 139.8 MB)

I'm using the [$lookup (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#syntax) to effectively do a join on my two tables based on a common field, but unlike a traditional SQL database, it's taking well **over 25 seconds** to complete the request.

I'm wondering how I can essentially improve the performance by adding an index to all of my documents in each collection to my `created_at` key (custom), and other fields?

```js
const client = new MongoClient(process.env.DB_CONNECTION)
await client.connect()

const results = await client.db().collection('data_source_one').aggregate([{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'data_source_two',
    localField: 'created_at',
    foreignField: 'created_at',
    as: 'combined_results'
  }
}]).toArray();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use indexes on specific fields to achieve a more efficient execution. MongoDB uses indexes to perform efficient querying of its collections. Without indexes, MongoDB must perform a collection scan, i.e. scan every document in a collection, to select those documents that match the query statement. If an appropriate index exists for a query, MongoDB can use the index to limit the number of documents it must inspect. You can check the documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/).

In your case, if you are joining two tables based on a common field, you can add an index to that field to achieve faster execution. You can check the documentation on optimizing your aggregation pipeline [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/). However, it probably still won't be as fast as the JOIN statements in SQL.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've added a few indexes and has gone from 25s to 700ms

Comment: keep in mind that if the lookup query result data is above 16MB in size , in that case lookup is going to fail.